# Android AlterDialog в со своим стилем

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

У меня есть AlertDialog со своим layout`ом и в нем есть две кнопки, можно ли как-нибуть связать кнопки с моего layout и функцонала alertDialog, PositiveButton и NegativeButton.

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.tobrighten_layout, null);
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setView(promptsView);
final EditText email_user = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.email_user);
email_user.setTypeface(typeFace);
final EditText textarea = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.textarea);
textarea.setTypeface(typeFace);

// String button1String = getString(R.string.send_fogot);
// String button2String = getString(R.string.fogot_cancel);

Button button1 = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.button1String);
Button button2 = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.button2String);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showMessage("Клик позитив");
    }
});

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showMessage("Клик негатив");
    }
});

builder.setPositiveButton(button1String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

    }
});

builder.setNegativeButton(button2String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //отложить
    }
});

builder.create();
builder.show();
```

Думаю из кода понятно что я хочу связать button1 с PositiveButton, а button2 с NegativeButton, но я не нашел как такое сделать, если уж такое сделать нельзя то я хотел бы positivButton и negativButton покрасить как мои кнопки, но как такое сделать я тоже не нашел. Нужна помощь.

Comment: @pavlofff просто я предполагаю, что если буду просто юзать onclick listener то alertDialog не будет закрываться, а так и будет висеть

Comment: @pavlofff так вот я не могу его вызвать из onclicklistener

Comment: @pavlofff я отказался от полного создания диалога потому что оно мне не подходит, мне проще вывести с layout`а

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы закрыть диалог при нажатии на кнопку на разметке диалога (отличие кнопок диалога от обычных кнопок на разметке в том, что они закрывают диалог после нажатия), нам нужно получить его экземпляр. Сделаем это через метод `create()` билдера (только необходимый код):

```
final AlertDialog adl = builder.create();
adl.show();
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showMessage("Клик негатив");
        adl.dismiss(); // закрываем диалог
    }
});
```